# How can I get a div that exists in the website's source code but not exists in the document?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a Chrome extension to classify the people who I am following in the website `www.zhihu.com`, because this website don't have this function.

when I view the source code of the website, I find my personal data is put in a div that whose id is named data.

[image]

[image]

So I want to obtain this div. But, when I log this div in the document, it becomes null.

[image]

Why does this happen? And how can I get a div that exists in the website's source code but not exists in the document?

Comment: it happens cuz they remove the div onload

Comment: wow, got it, thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

It could be several reason: first of all, the view source is not a live representation of the document, it's the source the server has sent to the client. It means, it might be no longer valid. Try to load this in the address bar (of a modern browser, possibly):

```
data:text,<div>hello</div><script>document.querySelector("div").remove()</script>
```

And check the view source. The source will contains the `div`, but if you use the inspector from devtools you will see that the `div` no longer exists (of course, we removed that by JS).

Another scenario, could be that you're logging from a different frame context: if the web pages contains frames, you might be in a frame context where your `div` is not present.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, by the way, if the div is removed by JS, could I have method to obtain it?

Comment: Not using DOM, the DOM is the living representation of your current document. You could probably do a fetch / XMLHttpRequest and parse the result without executing JS, but it's an additiona http request and I'm not sure if it's make sense.
Since you're doing a chrome extension, you could also try to add a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) before any JS is running. In this way you can check if the specific node is removed.